# This program is use to read the acceleration. Can anyone explain what does "int16_t pDataXYZ[3] = {0};" mean? BOLDED below

Tags: c, stm32, accelerometer

```
#include "main.h"
#include "app_x-cube-ai.h"
#include "ai_platform.h"
#include "network.h"
#include "network_data.h"
#include "stm32l475e_iot01.h"
#include "stm32l475e_iot01_accelero.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

This is the include file.

```
ai_handle network;
float aiInData[AI_NETWORK_IN_1_SIZE];
float aiOutData[AI_NETWORK_OUT_1_SIZE];
uint8_t activations[AI_NETWORK_DATA_ACTIVATIONS_SIZE];
const char* activities[AI_NETWORK_OUT_1_SIZE] = {
  "stationary", "walking", "running"
};
```

The main code reads here for displaying the  XYZ axis

```
int main(void)
{
  BSP_ACCELERO_Init();
  int16_t pDataXYZ[3] = {0}; // ?????

while (1)
  {
      BSP_ACCELERO_AccGetXYZ(pDataXYZ);
      snprintf(str_acc,100," X-axis = %d \n\r", pDataXYZ[0]);
      snprintf(str_acc,100," Y-axis = %d \n\r", pDataXYZ[1]);
      snprintf(str_acc,100," Z-axis = %d \n\r", pDataXYZ[2]);

      aiInData[write_index + 0] = (float) pDataXYZ[0] / 4000.0f;
      aiInData[write_index + 1] = (float) pDataXYZ[1] / 4000.0f;
      aiInData[write_index + 2] = (float) pDataXYZ[2] / 4000.0f;
      write_index += 3;

      if (write_index == AI_NETWORK_IN_1_SIZE) {
        write_index = 0;

        printf("Running inference\r\n");
        AI_Run(aiInData, aiOutData);

        /* Output results */
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < AI_NETWORK_OUT_1_SIZE; i++) {
          printf("%8.6f ", aiOutData[i]);
        }
        uint32_t class = argmax(aiOutData, AI_NETWORK_OUT_1_SIZE);
        printf(": %d - %s\r\n", (int) class, activities[class]);
      }
   }
}
```

What does write_index and pDataXYZ mean? Also how do you convert the XYZ axis into acceleration?
I cannot display the last line saying **printf(": %d - %s\r\n", (int) class, activities[class]);**

Comment: I can only manage to read the XYZ axis value but not the acceleration, how to get acceleartion reading?

Comment: You seem to have skipped some of the early chapters of your beginners C book, where it taught you about arrays and their initialization.

Comment: And please don't attempt formatting in code snippets, that just doesn't work. If you want to mark out a specific line mention it in the question and add a comment on the line (or the line above).

Comment: `write_index` seems to be an integer variable, but you the code you posted does not show its declaration. `int16_t pDataXYZ[3] = {0};` defines `pDataXYZ` as an array of 3 `int16_t` (16-bit) integers and initializes it to all zeros (element 0 is initialized explicitly and elements 1 and 2 are initialized implicitly). You could change it to `int16_t pDataXYZ[3] = {0, 0, 0};` if you want (initializing all 3 elements explicitly), and it would be initialized exactly the same.

Comment: I would suggest checking out https://www.reddit.com/r/CodingHelp/

Answer (score 0):

First I do not have enough reputation for comment so this is not a full answer. As Ian Abbott mentioned in the comments section the `pDataXYZ` it is just a 16 bit element size array initialized to 0, it seems that the function `BSP_ACCELERO_AccGetXYZ` is getting the acceleration in a specific format that is not described in your code, also the `str_acc` buffer is been loaded with the information of the `pDataXYZ` array but we can not know where it is been used only by taking a look to the code you share. `write_index` seems to be a base index where the information in the `aiInData` array should be but we can not be sure of it until you post all the code. Regarding the conversion you will need to give more information and investigate in the device data sheet the format of the data. this information could be in the division by 4000.0 or the `AI_Run` function.